# How copy method works in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

when I have `dg = df.copy()` in pandas dataframe, I know I have two dataframes where  dg is copy of df. But for `df = df.copy()`, does the new df overrides the old df? I mean in the RAM for `df = df.copy()` how many dataframes I have?

Comment: What you're looking for is a shallow vs deep copy. Might help to peruse through the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But for df = df.copy(), does the new df overrides the old df? I mean in the RAM for df = df.copy() how many dataframes I have?

This is **not** a question about Pandas or the DataFrame class. It is a question about the `=` operator in Python.

`df.copy()` creates a new object, which happens to be a new instance of the DataFrame class. That's all you have to know. (You do have to know this, because functions can return objects that already existed.) It will do this *exactly the same way* whether you write `dg = df.copy()` or `df = df.copy()` - it could not possibly matter, because there is no way for the method to know that the assignment is even going to happen.

Assignment [causes a name to refer to some particular object](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html). That's **it**. `dg = df.copy()` means "when you get the object back from `df.copy()`, let `dg` be a name for that object". `df = df.copy()` means "when you get the object back from `df.copy()`, let `df` (stop being a name for what it was naming before, and) be a name for that object".

Objects persist for as long as they have a name.

When you write `dg = df.copy()`, the `df` name is still a name for the original `DataFrame`, so now you necessarily have two `DataFrames` in memory.

When you write `df = df.copy()`, the `df` name is not a name for that original `DataFrame` any more, because it was changed to be a name for the new one. So now the old one **may or may not** still be in memory.

It will definitely still be in memory if it has any *other* names (or other references - for example, being an element of a list somewhere).

In the reference implementation, it will be freed up if that was the last remaining name for the object. This happens because the reference implementation uses reference-counting-based garbage collection. Other implementations (for example, Jython) may not do this; they may use any sort of garbage collection technique.

Answer (score 3):

From the official Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

> **DataFrame.copy(deep=True)**
>
> Make a copy of this object’s indices
> and data.
>
> When `deep=True` (default), a new object will be created with a copy of
> the calling object’s data and indices. Modifications to the data or
> indices of the copy will not be reflected in the original object (see
> notes below).
>
> When `deep=False`, a new object will be created without copying the
> calling object’s data or index (only references to the data and index
> are copied). Any changes to the data of the original will be reflected
> in the shallow copy (and vice versa).

So when you have `df = df.copy()`, you are just assigning the `df` object to the `df` variable name, so functionally nothing changes. It's overwritten, but stays the same. So you would still only have a single `df` object stored in memory.